# Image Positioning Changes in IE (All Versions) - Negative Margin Issue?

Tags: internet-explorer, margins, margin

www.goo.gl/HDx9c

You can see the difference here:
http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/8269/screenshot20120813at557.png

Any ideas? A negative margin is being used to pull the image "up" - I'm thinking that may have something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Since IE 8, you can try fix it easily using:

```
box-sizing: content-box
```

But it depends on rendering mode. Another way is fixing it by IE-specific CSS declarations in a conditional comment.